# Display the column values from sql using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

i have established a connection and i have a table named "MAP" in my database. i have two columns in the table, namely "LONG" "LAT". my table contains 3 rows of data's.

```
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(" select LONG from map ");
  ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
```

i have done the above code. can any one help me out to display the values of my 1st column. (i.e) "LONG"
The data type of the column is double.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the resultset object and display the result

```
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(" select LONG from map ");
if (resultSet.next()) {
    do {
        System.out.println(rs.getDouble("yourColumnName");
    } while(resultSet.next());
```

Comment: could you be more specific. i think you are displaying the column names of my table..!

Comment: in place of yourColumnName type your actual column you want to retrive data

Comment: Sorry. i forgot to do so.. your answer was also correct. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (rs.next()){
  double d = rs.getDouble("LONG");
  System.out.println(d);
}
```

here `while` lop will iterate upto `length` of records in `resultset` and `rs.getDouble` will get data of `columnName` which is name of `column in table` then store to variable `d` then print it.

Comment: If your problem solved then mark answer as accepted, so other will not visit your solved problem.